# I'm getting wrong result in php code where I have to return the total sum of all the numbers from a file

Tags: php, file, sum

I have to write a function that return the sum of all the numbers in a file.

The text file is `numbers.txt`:

```
1

1

2

3

5

8

13

21
```

The code I write is:

```php
function sumFromFileInput($fileName) {
    $total = 0;
    $file = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");
    while ($number = fgets($file)) {
        $total += $number;
    }
    fclose($file);
    return $total;
    
}
```

The output should be `54` whereas my output is `124712203354`.

Please help me to figure out what I did wrong.

Comment: Are you adding strings or integers to each other in this code? You might need to make sure you are adding integers! :) You might be able to use `(int)` here to [convert your strings to ints](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting) if need be.

Comment: If this _was_ string concatenation, then the result should not be `124712203354`, with the given input data. And PHP does not even do string concatenation with the `+` operator (that’s a JavaScript thing), using `+` in PHP with scalar values should always _force_ casting to int or float, and force actual addition.

Comment: Hi Sadia, If you have time, would it be possible to post the code you used to call your `sumFromFileInput()` function? When I run your code on my side, I get the total of `54`, and when I use my modified version of your code (in my post below), I also get a total of `54` but without the PHP Notice messages. I'm curious if there is more to your code that might have caused the part that was showing the `124712203354` result. I'm not sure if that is all one number (as an integer), or if it is a series of numbers that were printed to your console or web page somewhere, or if it is something else.

Comment: @CBroe Nice point about the `+` operator in terms of concatenation. I should have remembered that when I posted my earlier comment. Thanks for commenting!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `file()` for this purpose and simplifiy your code:

```
$trimmed = file('<provide file path here>', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

$sum = array_sum($trimmed);
echo $sum;
```

In case you added values as string into file then you need to convert them to Integer first.

Add below line before `array_sum()` line:

```
$trimmed = array_map('intval', $trimmed);
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you modify your code to be like this:

```
function sumFromFileInput($fileName) {
    $total = 0;
    $file = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");
    while ($number = fgets($file)) {
        // Making sure to add integer values here
        $total += (int)$number;
    }
    fclose($file);
    return $total;
    
}
```

I have the feeling that your number values from your input file are being read in as `string`s instead of `int`s. Using something like `(int)` should be able to help with this type of issue. You could also potentially use `(integer)` or `intval()` instead of `(int)` for the conversion part. More info about this can be found [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting).

**Update:**

After [seeing CBroe's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66487329/im-getting-wrong-result-in-php-code-where-i-have-to-return-the-total-sum-of-all/66487378#comment117541524_66487329), I removed my earlier part about the string concatenation conjecture.

When checking the `sumFromFileInput()` function locally and using `var_dump($number)` to show the `$number` variable's type, I can verify that it is a `string`. This is why I still recommend using something like `(int)`, like in my added lines of code earlier in this answer. Without doing that, I get PHP notices in PHP 7.3.19 for these values that read like: `PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in [...]`.

Interestingly enough, though, I still get a total of `54` (as an `int`) with your original posted code. This gets me to thinking: it would be interesting to see the code you used to call your `sumFromFileInput()` function, because perhaps that might help explain why your output was what now appears to me to be a running sum total of the `$total`.

Also, this might not be as important, but it looks like your `$fileName` parameter isn't currently being used in your `sumFromFileInput()` function. Maybe this could be connected in the future?

Answer (score 0):

```
function sumFromFileInput($fileName) {
    $total = 0;
    $file = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");
    
    while (!feof($file)) { #this will give you a true value until it reaches end of the numbers.txt last line
        $total += (int) fgets($file); # this will read file lines one by one
    }
    fclose($file);
    return $total;
    
}
```